# WCF Task-Based Operations Exception Handling and TPL

Tags: c#, wcf, task-parallel-library

I've got a `WCF` proxy that's using task-based operations.  I'm making a method call that's wrapped in a `Parallel.ForEach()`.  The service method I'm calling is a slow/long-running operation and occasionally returns exceptions.  I'm not able to catch these exceptions in my catch block - never hits the block.  The only way I'm able to catch exceptions is by using the synchronous service method.  How do I catch the exceptions using the async service method?  Is the exception being returned too late in the processing?

```
Parallel.ForEach(campaignResults.SelectMany(cd => cd), result =>
    {
        try
            {
                retList.TryAdd(client.SubmitRequestAsync(result.id, requestDetail), item.id);
            }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                // NEVER HIT ON EXCEPTION
                foreach (Exception e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
                    }
            }
     }
```

Comment: `FaultException<T>` should be thrown, shouldn't? Did you try to catch common `Exception`?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov...Yes, I did try to catch Exception and doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should not be catching an AggregateException but rather a general exception and move the AggregateException handling outside the Parrallel.ForEach loop.

[MSDN: Handle Exceptions in Parallel Loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you are using IIS to host your WCF service, just remember that there is a default 20 minute Idle Timeout unless changed. Background tasks do not count as non-idle requests and you might find IIS stops your WCF service because no  further requests are made before the 20 minute Idle Timeout.

Comment: @BigDaddy you said `Exception` catching doesn't work?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov...right, but in conjunction with the ConcurrentStack and AggregateException, it's the right solution.  Sorry if I misunderstood your question.